# Spring3 Security - SwitchUserFilter - Can we supply encrypted passwords in the implementation of UserDetailsService

Tags: authentication, spring-security

Usually the **authentication-provider** of the **authentication-manager** tag is associated with a **user-service-ref** property that points to a bean that implements **UserDetailsService**, but in my application, its **ref** property has been used that points to a bean that implements **AuthenticationProvider**. This bean encodes the password supplied by the user and compares it with the encoded password in the database. 
I have the following configuration in spring-security.xml

```
<beans:bean id="myAuthenticationProvider" class="com.mysecurity.server.security.MyAuthenticationProvider" />

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="eeAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

Now, if I use SwitchUserFilter, it requires a reference to a class that implements **UserDetailsService** like this :

```
<beans:bean id="switchUserProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userServices" />
    <beans:property name="switchUserUrl" value="/admin/switchUser" />
    <beans:property name="exitUserUrl" value="/exitUser" />
    <beans:property name="targetUrl" value="/" />
</beans:bean>
```

The problem is that **UserDetailsService** requires me to supply a password that it would match against the one provided by the user, but I am not storing the original password in the database. There is no option to supply a bean that implements the **AuthenticationProvider** interface (like in the **authentication-provider** property I mentioned above) or an option to tell spring that it needs to encode the password supplied before comparing it with the one I'm providing from the database. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SwitchUserFilter` doesn't actually do any password checking. If it did, that would imply that the admin user had to know the password for the account they were switching to, which is not normally the case. The best analogy is the use of `su` on unix.

So it shouldn't matter what value you supply for the password. I would create an adapter for your existing code, which implements `UserDetailsService` and returns a random generated value for the password in the `UserDetails` object. The only information that is really required is the username and authorities (plus any other custom data you want to make use of).